# Linux kernel debugging warning: No Symbol table is loaded

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have been trying to learn Linux kernel debugging and created a sample module with some export symbols.

`int rday_3 = 30;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(rday_3);`

after doing insmod, I am able to see dmesg of my init module and command `cat /proc/kallsyms` gives me the symbol loaded. But when i run the command `gdb /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic /proc/kcore`, it gives a warning

> Reading symbols from /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
>
> warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
>   [New process 1]
>   Core was generated by `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=FE4E68E74E689A63 loop=/ubunt'.
>
> ## 0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
>
> (gdb) whatis rday_3
>
> No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Then i added debug flags in my Makefile generated .ko file in debug mode. And i added the command `add-symbol-file hello_driver.ko 0x00`. The i got the result as

> (gdb) whatis rday_3
>
> type = int
>
> (gdb) p rday_3
>
> Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Can anyone help me out with whats going wrong and what more i need to add?

Answer (score 2):

You must give the right address of your module section.

```
$ cat /sys/module/YOURMODULE/sections/.text
0xYOURMODULEADDRESS
```

and load the symbol:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file hello_driver.ko 0xYOURMODULEADDRESS
```

you may need to add more sections addresses depending which section the variable lays. see `help add-symbol-file` in gdb